# Bar plot X axis not in numerical order

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot using ggplot2 a bar graph. With the x values being different ranges ( SO x1= 0-10, x2= 11-20, x3= 21-30, ...... until 91-100, and the last range is ">100"). When i plot my graph with the corresponding y values as follows:

```
ggplot(data=figure1_data, aes(x=Average.Coverage.of.Study, y=Number.of.Studies)) + geom_bar(stat = "Identity")
```

The ">100" x value comes first in the plot and not at the end which is where I want it. How would I get it to come after the 91-100 range x value?? Can someone please help - I am very new to R. much appreciated!! :)

Comment: You need to set the order of factor levels/labels correctly. Check help(factor) to see how it is done.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

You need to order levels by your preference.

```
df <- data.frame(avg = c("0-10","11-20","21-30","91-100",">100"),
                 studies = c(1:5))
ggplot(df)+
  geom_bar(aes(x = ordered(avg, levels = c(avg)), y = studies), stat = "identity")
```

or

```
ggplot(df)+
  geom_bar(aes(x = ordered(avg, levels = c("0-10","11-20","21-30","91-100",">100")), y = studies), stat = "identity")`
```

will both give you the same result.

[image: ordered barplot]

Comment: No my data is arranged 0-10, 11-20, 21-30, .....91-100, and finally '>100'. I dont think its that